# SQLite file with password protection

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm using sqlite to store some user work information in android mobile app. and weekly create a backup of this database file in different directory(which is accessible).

My main question is this:

Is it possible to set password to open this sqlite file.

like this:

[image]

If there are possible advice, please share with me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try this http://sqlite-crypt.com/index.htm for encrypt your data

Comment: Thanks gabriel for your response and suggestion but i need password protected dialog like above picture.Is it possible in android.?